# Div moves horizontally to the right after I set the width above 100%

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a website where I am using an already programmed slider. Today I wanted to restructure the page a bit and when I set the div of the slider to over 100% in width, the div kept moving to the right.... So the f.ex. 20% from 120% were added to the right and the div was not placed in the center of the page anymore.

Is this normal? How do I keep the div centered? The id of the div is "beforeafter".

```html
<style>

.credits {
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#beforeafter {
  width: 150%;
  max-width: 150%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* Plugin CSS */
.twentytwenty-horizontal .twentytwenty-handle:before,
.twentytwenty-horizontal .twentytwenty-handle:after,
.twentytwenty-vertical .twentytwenty-handle:before,
.twentytwenty-vertical .twentytwenty-handle:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 30;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
}
.twentytwenty-horizontal .twentytwenty-handle:before,
.twentytwenty-horizontal .twentytwenty-handle:after {
  width: 3px;
  height: 9999px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1.5px;
}
.twentytwenty-vertical .twentytwenty-handle:before,
.twentytwenty-vertical .twentytwenty-handle:after {
  width: 9999px;
  height: 3px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.5px;
}
.twentytwenty-before-label,
.twentytwenty-after-label,
.twentytwenty-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.twentytwenty-before-label,
.twentytwenty-after-label,
.twentytwenty-overlay {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.twentytwenty-before-label,
.twentytwenty-after-label {
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
  -moz-transition-property: opacity;
  transition-property: opacity;
}
.twentytwenty-before-label:before,
.twentytwenty-after-label:before {
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
.twentytwenty-before-label:before,
.twentytwenty-after-label:before {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  line-height: 38px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.twentytwenty-horizontal .twentytwenty-before-label:before,
.twentytwenty-horizontal .twentytwenty-after-label:before {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -19px;
}
.twentytwenty-vertical .twentytwenty-before-label:before,
.twentytwenty-vertical .twentytwenty-after-label:before {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -45px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90px;
}
.twentytwenty-left-arrow,
.twentytwenty-right-arrow,
.twentytwenty-up-arrow,
.twentytwenty-down-arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px inset transparent;
  position: absolute;
}
.twentytwenty-left-arrow,
.twentytwenty-right-arrow {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
}
.twentytwenty-up-arrow,
.twentytwenty-down-arrow {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
}
.twentytwenty-container {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
}
.twentytwenty-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
}
.twentytwenty-container.active .twentytwenty-overlay,
.twentytwenty-container.active:hover.twentytwenty-overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.twentytwenty-container.active .twentytwenty-overlay .twentytwenty-before-label,
.twentytwenty-container.active .twentytwenty-overlay .twentytwenty-after-label,
.twentytwenty-container.active:hover.twentytwenty-overlay .twentytwenty-before-label,
.twentytwenty-container.active:hover.twentytwenty-overlay .twentytwenty-after-label {
  opacity: 0;
}
.twentytwenty-container * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.twentytwenty-before-label {
  opacity: 0;
}
.twentytwenty-horizontal .twentytwenty-before-label:before {
  left: 10px;
}
.twentytwenty-horizontal .twentytwenty-after-label:before {
  right: 10px;
}
.twentytwenty-vertical .twentytwenty-before-label:before {
  top: 10px;
}
.twentytwenty-vertical .twentytwenty-after-label:before {
  bottom: 10px;
}
.twentytwenty-overlay {
  -webkit-transition-property: background;
  -moz-transition-property: background;
  transition-property: background;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 25;
}

.twentytwenty-overlay:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.twentytwenty-overlay:hover .twentytwenty-after-label {
  opacity: 1;
}
.twentytwenty-overlay:hover .twentytwenty-before-label {
  opacity: 1;
}
.twentytwenty-before {
  z-index: 20;
}
.twentytwenty-after {
  z-index: 10;
}
.twentytwenty-handle {
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -22px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1000px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1000px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
  z-index: 40;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.twentytwenty-horizontal .twentytwenty-handle:before {
  bottom: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 white, 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 white, 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 white, 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
}
.twentytwenty-horizontal .twentytwenty-handle:after {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 22px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -3px 0 white, 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 -3px 0 white, 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 -3px 0 white, 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
}
.twentytwenty-vertical .twentytwenty-handle:before {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 22px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 0 0 white, 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 0 0 white, 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 3px 0 0 white, 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
}
.twentytwenty-vertical .twentytwenty-handle:after {
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: 22px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 0 0 white, 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: -3px 0 0 white, 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
  box-shadow: -3px 0 0 white, 0px 0px 12px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
}
.twentytwenty-left-arrow {
  border-right: 6px solid white;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -17px;
}
.twentytwenty-right-arrow {
  border-left: 6px solid white;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -17px;
}
.twentytwenty-up-arrow {
  border-bottom: 6px solid white;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
}
.twentytwenty-down-arrow {
  border-top: 6px solid white;
  bottom: 50%;
  margin-bottom: -17px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! CSS without HTML is useless for us to debug. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Where is your HTML code so we can help you??

Comment: I built the page in webflow, so it's kind of difficult for me to export and identify this part of the code... The only custom code i added is the following:

`<div id="beforeafter" class="twentytwenty-container">
  <img src="..." alt="Before">
  <img src="..." alt="After"/>
</div>`